# recharts synchronize x-axis for two datasets

Tags: dataset, bar-chart, linechart, recharts

I'm trying to set up my graph so that it will display barcharts (`dataset 1`) and linecharts (`dataset 2`) simultaneously.
However, when I set this up, the x-axis doesn't really sync up together. Is there a way to get the x-axis to sync up for the two datasets? For example, 350 from dataset2 matches on top of 350 from dataset1? The length of dataset2 is about ~200 and the length of dataset1 is about ~2000.
Here is the graph from recharts:

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
  const barChart = chartData[0] ? (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" aspect={2}>
      <ComposedChart data={chartData} barGap={0}>
        <XAxis dataKey="strike_price" xAxisId={0} />
        <XAxis dataKey="strike_price" xAxisId={1} hide />
        <XAxis dataKey="strike_price" xAxisId={2} hide />
        <XAxis dataKey="strike_price" xAxisId={3} axisLine={false} />
        <YAxis tickFormatter={formatNumbers} yAxisId={0} />
        <YAxis tickFormatter={formatNumbers} yAxisId={1} orientation="right" />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Bar
          data={chartData}
          dataKey="c_notion_expo"
          fill="green"
          xAxisId={0}
          barSize={100}
          fillOpacity={0.9}
        />
        <Bar
          data={chartData}
          dataKey="p_notion_expo"
          fill="red"
          xAxisId={1}
          barSize={100}
          fillOpacity={0.9}
        />
        <Bar
          data={chartData}
          dataKey="total_notional_exposure"
          fill="black"
          barSize={50}
          xAxisId={2}
          fillOpacity={0.9}
        />
        <Line
          data={theoData}
          type="monotone"
          dataKey="total_gamma"
          xAxisId={3}
          yAxisId={1}
        />
      </ComposedChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  ) : null;
```